# select context variables properties based on other variables in thymeleaf (dynamically)

Tags: templates, thymeleaf, spring-el

I am a beginner in using Thymeleaf. I have an object which is set as a context variable.
`ctx.setVariable("name", myObject);`

this object has several properties, but I can't just select them using
`name.property1.subproperty1'

because at some point I want to render `name.property1.subproperty` and `name.property2.subproperty` in the same template, and I don't want to hardcode this selection in the template because it might change.

I was thinking to declare another context variable like:

`String[] listOfProperties = {"property1", "property2"};`
`ctx.setVariable("properties", listOfProperties);`

and do something like that in the template:

`${myObject.?[listOfProperties[0]].subproperty1}`
`${myObject.?[listOfProperties[1]].subproperty2}`

In other words, I want to control from java code what property to be renderd.
I have templates for properties and I don't want to create more templates for the same type, because if I include the property template into myObject Template it is going to be rendered only once, that is why I chose this approach.

I am sorry I don't know to explain better...
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following syntax (see: [4.12 Preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html#preprocessing)):

```
${myObject.?__${listOfProperties[0]}__.subproperty1} ${myObject.?__${listOfProperties[1]}__.subproperty2}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes it works, without the question mark. But I switched to Parameterizable fragment signatures: [link](http://www.thymeleaf.org/whatsnew21.html#fsig) now, it seems to be e better solution.