# Dynamic variable ID

Tags: thymeleaf

I allow the user to create some customized fields... therefore, I don't know their IDs. While showing such fields in the view, I need to use the value of one variable and use it to get the value of another variable. Currently, th:value="${udfield.id}" will of course only assign the value of "udfield.id". Is this possible?

```
<div data-th-each="udfield : ${udfields}">
    <label th:text="${udfield.displayText}">User defined field:</label>
    <input th:name="${udfield.id}" type="text" class="form-control" th:value="${udfield.id}"/>
</div>
```

My Controller sends the values which were extracted from a DB:

```
for (FieldValue currentFieldVal : userFieldValues){
    attributes.addFlashAttribute(currentFieldVal.getFieldID(), currentFieldVal.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What I needed was [preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing), I found it thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19784592/select-context-variables-properties-based-on-other-variables-in-thymeleaf-dynam).

```
th:value="${__${udfield.id}__}"
```

Comment: Thank you for updating - was useful to me, as well.